# NSView loaded from nib file has disabled controls and actions doesn't work too

Tags: swift, cocoa, nib, appkit

I have a hierarchy of views loaded from nib files. Last (deepest) level is like this:

```
let xValue =  (point as! DynamicPoint).xValue
let xViewController =  DynamicValuePanelViewController(nibName: "DynamicValuePanelView", value: xValue)
xValueView.addSubview(xViewController.view)
```

OK, it almost works. I can see in NIB NSView values of `xValue` object like its `name`, `value`, some [String] array for NSPopUpButton values.
But if I connect `NSTextField` action to File's Owner it's never fired. If I bind value – getter works, setter – never. I added `NSPopupButton`, and bind values – yes, they're in menu but they are disabled, action from button never fired. What could cause such a strange one-way behavior? I can get everything, but set nothing.

Comment: Is `xViewController` released when it goes out of scope?

Comment: Maybe not. How to do it?

Comment: Do you keep a strong reference to `xViewController`?

Comment: Yes (I think) as `var`, not `weak var.` (Is it a strong/weak reference?Should be weak?)

Comment: `let xViewController =` is a local `xViewController`. Do you also have a `var xViewController`?

Comment: No, it's only local, inited on the fly in `awakeFromNib` in nested controllers, fired by Notification. I need different set of views for different conditions.

Comment: A local variable gets deallocated when it goes out of scope. Create a property to keep a strong reference.

Comment: You have right. It helped, now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Willeke said — NSViewControllers must have strong reference. Can't create them „on the fly”.

```
class SomeController:NSViewController {

    var xViewController: DynamicValuePanelViewController!
    @IBOutlet var xValueView: NSView!

    func loadView(for xValue: SomeCustomObject) {
         xViewController =  DynamicValuePanelViewController(nibName: "DynamicValuePanelView", value: xValue)
         xValueView.addSubview(xViewController.view)

    }
}
```